# Moving all files of nested folders to other folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I have an hierarchy of folders like this:

```
MainFolder
|
| - 01
| - 02
| - 03
| - 04
| - 05
| - 06
| - 07
| - 08
| - 09
| - 10
```

And inside each of this ten folders, I have other 10 folders, and so on. In total, I have 10 levels.

I would like to move ALL files, including ALL possible extensions (including zip and rar) to a folder called FinalFolder.

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
find MainFolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t FinalFolder
```

And is "working". In total, I'm catching 5k files, but I know that I have 25k files, so is not catching all. What could be the problem? And more important, how to fix it?

Comment: cp -r (directory)   (destination)  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/195983/how-to-copy-files-via-terminal

Comment: Is there an advantage to that over a simpler `find MainFolder -type f -exec mv  \{\} FinalFolder \;`  ?

Comment: Isn't working @DavidGolding, is copying all the structure.

Comment: Let my try @infixed.

Comment: Same result :/.

Comment: You're not targeting the same folder without clearing the old result, are you?

Comment: actually isn't every time this is tried going to change the experiment.  If the command works partially, stuff has disappeared from MainFolder, so the next time you run, its not the same initial conditions

Comment: rename the last test's FinalFolder to CopiedFolder, then make an empty folder and try mine again `rm -rf FinalFolder; mkdir FinalFolder; find CopiedFolder -type f -exec mv \{\} FinalFolder \;`  (this includes making an empty FinalFolder)

Comment: Is totally working!!!! :)))

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you post as an answer?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simpler find command to flatten the source directory.

**Alert**: Make sure the target directory exists first!! (or you could end up with **one** file named FinalFolder with only **one** of your files in it)

```
 find MainFolder -type f -exec mv \{\} FinalFolder \;
```

EDIT

This can overwrite files if you have two or more that have a name collision.  If you want to avoid that you can get version numbers appended by using the `cp` command in place of `mv`.  This has the side effect that the original directory tree remains intact, so one might need to go and delete it after processing.

```
 find MainFolder -type f -exec cp --backup=numbered \{\} FinalFolder \;
```

If this keeps asking for confirmation it is probably due to the `cp` command being aliased to `cp -i`.  In which case use `/bin/cp` in place of `cp`

Comment: you know, it'd probably be safer to use `ln` to make a new link for each file inside the target folder, then `rm -rf` the source folder when you were happy.

Comment: nevermind.  too hard to make `basename`.   "{}" does not seem to expand right inside backticks executed by find

Comment: apparently `find MainFolder -type f -exec ln \{\} FinalFolder \;` will work without needing the `basename` command to explicitly creating a base name though

Comment: One question: If i have a bunch of files with the same name, what happens? Can i automatically rename it?

Comment: what will happen now is the last one done will overwrite the previous.  You could use `mv` with the `-n` no-clobber switch and the other files would stay in MainFolder.   But if you want a version number, you probably should start a new question

Comment: if you use `cp` instead of `mv` you can get version numbers with `cp -backup=numbered srcfile destfile`   Oddly enough my `cp` command was aliased to `cp -i`, so I had to use `/bin/cp -backup=numbered` to make it work without asking confirmations