# Moving all files of nested folders to other folder but without overwrite

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In my [previous](https://superuser.com/questions/1053688/moving-all-files-of-nested-folders-to-other-folder/1053760?noredirect=1#comment1477752_1053760) question i was trying to push all my files inside folders and subfolders. Now i can with the command:

```
 find MainFolder -type f -exec mv \{\} FinalFolder \;
```

Now, i would like to avoid overwrite. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mv` recipe can overwrite files if you have two or more that have a name collision. If you want to avoid that you can get version numbers appended by using the cp command in place of mv.

```
find MainFolder -type f -exec cp --backup=numbered \{\} FinalFolder \;
```

Then you your duplicate files will have numbers in curly braces as version numbers appended to them if they collide

If `cp` keeps asking for confirmations, it might be because  the `cp` command being aliased to `cp -i` fore saftey.  A common initialization. In that case use `/bin/cp` in place of the `cp`

The original directory structure will still be there after running.  If you don't want it. just `rm -rf MainFolder` it when you are sure you are done with it

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` switch for `mv` is what you're after. From the manpage:

-n, --no-clobber
          do not overwrite an existing file

Baking this into your find script results in this:

```
find MainFolder -type f -exec mv -n \{\} FinalFolder \;
```

Comment: I believe this would make files be left behind in MainFolder if they duplicate a name